# Redsys con NodeJS y CryptoJS

Tags: nodejs

Estoy realizando un proyecto con NodeJS, y estoy desarrollando la pasarela de pago.

El problema es que al generar la firma, da error SIS0042 -> La firma enviada no es correcta.

La firma la genero de la siguiente manera:

```
var merchant = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(this.generateMerchantParams(payment))).toString('base64');

var secretKey = new Buffer(secret, 'base64');

var cipher = _crypto.TripleDES.encrypt(order_id, secret);

var order_encoded = cipher.ciphertext.toString(_crypto.enc.Base64);

var hexMac256 = _crypto.HmacSHA256(merchant, _crypto.enc.Base64.parse(order_encoded));
```

Con la firma (Ds_Signature: **hexMac256**), Ds_MerchantParameters (**merchant**), y Ds_SignatureVersion (**HMAC_SHA256_V1**), generamos el formulario que redirige a la pantalla del banco.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con este problema? Cualquier ayuda será agradecida.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: valdría también para Angular ?

Answer (score 4):

Yo también he estado dedicando bastantes horas a averiguar cómo implementar esto en Node.js. Te dejo el código que funciona. Lo difícil fue darme cuenta de que RedSys no quiere "padding" en el 3DES y entender cómo almacena CryptoJS su información.

```
// Base64 encoding of parameters
var merchantWordArray = cryptojs.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(tpvdata));
var merchantBase64 = merchantWordArray.toString(cryptojs.enc.Base64);

// Decode key
var keyWordArray = cryptojs.enc.Base64.parse(merchant_key);

// Generate transaction key
var iv = cryptojs.enc.Hex.parse("0000000000000000");
var cipher = cryptojs.TripleDES.encrypt(tpvdata.DS_MERCHANT_ORDER, keyWordArray, {
  iv:iv,
  mode: cryptojs.mode.CBC,
  padding: cryptojs.pad.ZeroPadding
});

// Sign
var signature = cryptojs.HmacSHA256(merchantBase64, cipher.ciphertext);
var signatureBase64 = signature.toString(cryptojs.enc.Base64);

// Done, we can return response
var response = {
  signatureVersion: "HMAC_SHA256_V1",
  merchantParameters: merchantBase64,
  signature: signatureBase64
};
```

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente....:)

Para mayor claridad incluir el import de la libreria de encriptación: 

    let cryptojs = require("crypto-js");

Comment: Alguien sabe como podría recuperar en la respuesta de RedSys el identificador del pago a partir de los parametros encriptados?